# Helper method to load images abandoning memory in iOS - how do I avoid this?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, profiler

I have a helper class I created to make it easy to load images throughout my app - it get's used ALOT:

```
@implementation Helpers

+(UIImage *) getThumbnailImageIfExists:(NSString *)ItemSKU withManufacturer: (NSNumber *) aManufacturerID { 

    @autoreleasepool {

    NSString *fileName = [[[SharedFunctions sharedInstance] getLargeFileName:[aManufacturerID stringValue] withPhotoName:ItemSKU] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_lg.jpg" withString:@"_tn.jpg"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName lowercaseString]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savePath];

    if  (imageData==nil) 
    {
         return nil;
    }

    return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    }
}

@end
```

I am using the Profiler to see why my app keeps crashing.  I am using the Leaks tool and Heapshots to see what is hanging around in abandoned memory - looks like this is killing me.

How can I fix this method?  This is an old project that was converted to ARC.

Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the issue is here and not with whatever code makes use of these images?

Comment: no I am not, I might have made some assumptions when I converted this project to ARC - as you can see my heapshot growth is ridiculous

Comment: @rmaddy it looks like you were right, this is an old project that started as supporting iOS 4.  It had a bunch of delegates not set as weak, so the entire view was being abandoned into memory - add as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an autoreleased object (`imageWithData`) inside an autorelease pool, returning that, but then immediately draining your pool. The simplest fix would be to remove that autorelease pool. Why have that pool at all? Just to drain the `NSData` immediately? But you don't need that `NSData` at all since you could just retrieve the image directly:

```
@implementation Helpers

+ (UIImage *) getThumbnailImageIfExists:(NSString *)ItemSKU withManufacturer: (NSNumber *) aManufacturerID { 

    NSString *fileName = [[[SharedFunctions sharedInstance] getLargeFileName:[aManufacturerID stringValue] withPhotoName:ItemSKU] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_lg.jpg" withString:@"_tn.jpg"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName lowercaseString]];

    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savePath];
}

@end
```

If you really want to make sure that the various string and array variables (namely, the `fileName`, `paths`, `documentsPath` and `savePath`) don't get put into the caller's autorelease pool, you could solve that problem, but I'm not sure how critical that is (at least in comparison to the `NSData` that would have been put in the pool).

---

Consider this alternative implementation:

```
+ (UIImage *)getThumbnailImageIfExists:(NSString *)itemSKU withManufacturer:(NSNumber *)aManufacturerID
{
    UIImage *image;
    static NSString *documentsPath;
    static NSCache *cache;

    // create docsPath and cache once and only once

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        documentsPath = searchPaths[0];
        cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
        cache.countLimit = 100;
    });

    // now do your image retrieval

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *fileName = [[[SharedFunctions sharedInstance] getLargeFileName:[aManufacturerID stringValue] withPhotoName:itemSKU] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_lg.jpg" withString:@"_tn.jpg"];
        NSString *savePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName lowercaseString]];

        image = [cache objectForKey:savePath];
        if (!image)
        {
            image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:savePath]; // note, not an autoreleased object
            [cache setObject:image forKey:savePath];
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

I'm doing a couple of things here:

1. Like before, I've removed the unnecessary `NSData` logic. No need to load the file into a `NSData` and then create a `UIImage` from that, only to then discard the `NSData`.
2. If you're calling this image repeated for the same SKU/manufacturer, there will be a huge memory savings (as well as a performance improvement) by using `NSCache` to store images it loads. It prevents you from creating duplicate images if you happen to request the same image multiple times. Using `NSCache` solves that problem. By I'm keying the `NSCache` by the filename of your image, which is a convenient key to use (though you could also use some string composed from manufacturer code and the SKU; it's up to you).
3. I've availing myself of `dispatch_once` to set two static variables:

   - the `documentsPath` (which has an observable affect if you're calling this tens of thousands of times, the improvement will probably not be observable if you're calling this only a few hundred times)
   - the `cache` (and if you want your cache to persist across instances of calls to this method, you need to either do something like, making it `static`, this to make sure it persists, but setting it once via `dispatch_once`)

   To be frank, I'd be inclined to move `documentsPath` and/or the `cache` as instance variables of some singleton instance and set these variables in the appropriate `init` method rather than using `dispatch_once`, but I was trying to show you how you could do it just by modifying the method you shared with us.
4. Really minor change, but I always use camelCase (starting with lowercase letter) for variable names, so I've changed `ItemSKU` to `itemSKU`.
5. While I've employed your [`@autoreleasepool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) block, that's generally not needed unless you're calling this method tons of times from within a single `for` loop, for example. If these are thumbnails used in table view or collection view, the `@autoreleasepool` block is not needed. But I've kept that in there in case one of these very special scenarios applies.

   Personally, I use `@autoreleasepool` blocks around self-contained blocks of code, not code that is returning some value. But if you're situation necessitates it, you can do something like the above.

The use of the `cache` will have huge impact (both in terms of memory consumption and performance) if you're calling this method more than once for the same image. The use of `static` and `dispatch_once` for `documentsPath` has modest performance impact, but if you're calling this *a lot*, then its becomes noticeable and a refinement you might want to consider.

The use of `@autoreleasepool` block is useful if you see memory increase, but falls back to a reasonable level later, when it's done, but you simply want to reduce that "high water mark". If the problem is that memory is never dropping down at all, then auto release pools will not help you; the problem rests elsewhere.

You should play around with this yourself, run it through the profiler, and check the performance and memory usage. Personally, I would generally focus on the use of cache and not be so worried about `@autoreleasepool` unless there is something peculiar about how you're calling this method (e.g. you're calling it thousands and thousands of times in a single `for` loop), but it's something to consider. For most scenarios, the real benefit will come from the use of the cache, not the `@autorelease` block.

Comment: I was just trying anything with that autorelease pool, this solution still gives me the same amount of heap growth :(

Comment: @Slee It doesn't seem possible possible that it has the same amount of heap growth, because we've taken out one of the biggest items, the `NSData`. Clearly you can't get rid of the image (because that's what you're returning and you presumably need that). I suspect that rmaddy is right, that the problem rests in the calling routine. Can you share what that's doing? Also, are you possibly calling this more than once for the same thumbnail? If so, you should use `NSCache` for these images, which would dramatically reduce the memory usage.

Comment: @Slee I've revised answer after some testing. The real question is how is this `getThumbnailImageIfExists` method is being called. But hopefully my expanded answer will get you thinking about other ideas. By the way, I assume you're using ARC. If not, you'll need the appropriate `release` and `autorelease` statements.

Comment: thanks for this hugely insightful answer, this will help me for sure - I have not implemented NSCache before and I load at least a 100 images at a time all of the time. My main issue was old delegate declarations from iOS 4.3 that never got updated properly to ARC - so my uiviewcontroller and all of it's UIViews and UIImages were getting retained in memory never to be released.

Comment: @Slee Agreed, if you have retain cycle or leak (by your `strong` delegates, for example, fix that), then fixing that is simply essential. The other fixes are situational: If the app will ever be calling this method repeatedly for the same image, then use cache. If memory is being relieved, but just not quickly enough, look at your `@autoreleasepool` setting to reduce the high water mark. It simply depends upon what problem you're solving.

Comment: @Slee by the way, you say you're loading over 100 images at the same time. If all 100 images are not visible at the same time, then that's probably a design flaw. You should generally load what images you need at the time (called "lazy loading") and as you scroll, release images that are no longer visible and load new images as they scroll on. It's a pattern you see in table views and collection views. But you generally do *not* load in tons of images at the same time (unless they're all visible at the same time).

Comment: There are at most 25 images (thumbnails) shown at once - they get lazy loaded - it is like  catalog so these images get loaded and unload all of the time - so the cache should really help I would imagine